# How to validate if a decimal number is in a sequence 0.001, 0.002, ..., 2.048

Tags: javascript

For integers [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...] I can use this function:

```
const validate = num => (num & num - 1) == 0;
```

Is there an elegant similar way to do it with decimal numbers without using loops?

- 0.001
- 0.002
- 0.004
- ...
- 2.048

And it should be possible to use any number of digits after the decimal point based on a **initial value**.

- 0.0001 (**initial value**)
- 0.0002
- 0.0004
- 0.0016
- ...
- 1.6384

Now I use the function to determine if there are numbers after decimal comma and count them:

```
countDecimals(num) {
  if (Math.floor(num.valueOf()) === num.valueOf()) return 0;
  return num.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0;
}
```

and then I use it:

```
validateEntryValue(entryValue) {
  const decimalsQuantity = this.countDecimals(entryValue);
  if (decimalsQuantity) {
    const numToMul = Math.pow(10, decimalsQuantity);
    return ((entryValue * numToMul) & (entryValue * numToMul) - 1) == 0;
  }
  return (entryValue & entryValue - 1) == 0;
}
```

But some result values fail the tests:

- 0.001 (**initial value**)
- 0.002
- 0.004
- 0.016
- 0.02 (should not to be validated because an **initial value is not 0.01**)

Comment: sorry, can you please explain when a number is valid and when not? you want to check whether that decimal value is..?

Comment: You should take into account, that [floating point math can be inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/8376184).

Comment: What is your input? Is it just a number or an array? Also there in no mention of initial value in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [doing math with floating point numbers can be inaccurate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/8376184), so verifying them (which requires an **exact** value) might not work well.

**So, you can multiply your number, so that it's an integer**, to avoid precision issues and then you can even use your solution on it.

Here's a purely mathematical solution:

```js
const validate = (toVerify, initial) => {
  const num = toVerify / initial //division is like multiplication with the reciprocal!
  return (num & num - 1) == 0
};

console.log(validate(8, 1)) //true
console.log(validate(0.08, 0.01)) //true
console.log(validate(0.008, 0.001)) //true
console.log(validate(0.016, 0.001)) //true
console.log(validate(0.08, 0.001)) //false
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In a Geometric Progression the "nth" term is equal to `a * r ** (n-1)`

> `a` First Term
>
> `n-1` nth term in 0 index
>
> `r` Common Ratio

You can simply check if the array element obeys the expression mentioned above.

```js
const validateSeq = (seq) => {
  const 
    ratio = (seq[1] || seq[0]) / seq[0],
    res = seq.map((s, i) => seq[0] * ratio ** i === s);
  return res;
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(validateSeq([0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.2, 0.16])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(validateSeq([1, 2, 8, 20, 16])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(validateSeq([0.01])));
```

Comment: @ВадимХамзин Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues?

Comment: OP appearently has a *geometric* progression (rather than an *arithmetic* one), with a common ratio of 2.

Comment: @FZs Oh thanks a lot for pointing that, I will update my answer

Comment: He needs a javascript function that takes only one number as input and returns true if that number is 2^n/1000, where n is an unknown integer.